# Django fetch data from two table related to foreign key

Tags: django

I want to fetch data from one model and related images means I want to get vehicle id and related to that vehiceid its related images based on F key relationship.

Model1

```
from django.db import models

class VehicleAd(models.Model):
    vehiclename = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

model 2

```
from django.db import models
from .vehiclead import VehicleAd

class Vehicleadimages(models.Model):
    vehiclead = models.ForeignKey(VehicleAd, on_delete=models.CASCADE,enter code hererelated_name="relatedvehiclead")
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to="images/vechileadimage")
```

views

```
def viewVehiclead(request):

    vehiclead = VehicleAd.objects.all()
    vehicleadimages = Vehicleadimages.objects.all()
    print(vehiclead)

    context = {
        'vehiclead':vehiclead,
        'vehicleadimages': vehicleadimages
    }

    return render(request,'vehiclead/view.html',context)
```

template

```
{% block body %}
<div class="container bg-color-w shadow-lg custom-style-cont ">
    {% include "menu/top-menu.html" %}

    <div class="col-md-12 pd-arn2prc">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 mx-auto">
                    <h1>h2</h1>
                    <table>
                        {% for v in vehiclead %}
                        <a href="#">{{ v.vehicleadimages.image }}</a>
                        {% endfor %}
                    </table>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
{% endblock body %}
```

Comment: Inside your template you can use reverse lookup for each vehicle object
`{% for img in v.relatedvehiclead.all %} <img src={{ img.image.url }}>{% endfor %}`
Here `relatedvehiclead` is the `related_name` attribute of your model field `vehiclead ` in `Vehicleadimages` model.

Comment: thanks Akash. it worked. but if i need the first image only?

Comment: `v.relatedvehiclead.all.0.image.url`

Comment: great. i have 2 models. 1 vehicleads 2. vehicleimages so ill show a list of vechicleads data where i just want to show the first image associated with vechicleads

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`v.vehicleadimages` returns all the images. It's a queryset not an object meaning you can't call `.image` on.

You can either use a for loop:

```
{% for v in vehiclead %}
    {% for image in v.vehicleadimages.all %}
        <a href="#">{{ image.image }}</a>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If you need the first image:

```
<a href="#">{{ v.vehicleadimages.first.image }}</a>
```

or

```
<a href="#">{{ v.vehicleadimages.all.0.image }}</a>
```

And there is also `with` tag:

```
{% with item.itemimage_set.all|first as image %}
    <a href="#">{{ image.image }}</a>
{% endwith %}
```